# Jenkins on k8s and pipeline with docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run my Jenkins behind k8s. We can achieve that with any standard helm chart or our own manifest files. In this case, Jenkins (master only) will run inside a container (Pod).

Now I also want to have a pipeline job that uses docker agent as described [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

I am getting confused, about

- how and where this docker container will be run (on the same node where Jenkins is running? and suppose the node capacity is over then it needs to run docker agent on a different node)
- how does Jenkins will authenticate to run containers on k8s nodes?
- I saw the Kubernetes plugin/docker plugin. But those plugins create containers beforehand (*or at least we need to set up a template, which decides how containers will start, which image will be used and many more*) and connects Jenkins with help of JNLP / ssh. I lose the flexibility to have an image as an agent in that case.
- going further, I also like to build custom images on the fly with help of Dockerfile shipped along with code. An example is available in the same [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this documentation is answering all of your questions: https://devopscube.com/jenkins-build-agents-kubernetes/

With this method, you are not losing your flexibility because your Jenkins master going to create a K8s pod on the fly. Yes, additionally you need JNLP authentication but you can think of that as a sidecar container.

About your first question: If you use exactly that way, your Jenkins jobs going to run under Jenkins master with the same Docker that your Jenkins Master is using.

Comment: No this is not what I am looking for. As I mentioned in the question, I already looked at the Kubernetes plugin. This blog is explaining how to set up this plugin. The main limitation here is I can not use any docker image on the fly. I need to define a container template. I also want to define Dockerfile only. Jenkins (standalone) builds an image out of it. Please check the link I provided in the question.

Comment: @Guru After you made a configuration like mentioned at the link, rest of them completely up to you. You can either use image or Dockerfile. As an alternative, you can add additional stage as initial stage you can build your Dockerfile and with this way you can be sure your image going to be used on new agent. Of course you should restrict k8s nodes to use same docker.sock